# Export CSV From Postgres VIA Command Line

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api, psql

*Hello Stack Overflowers!*
I'm currently exporting a Postgres table as a .csv using a C# application I developed. I'm able to export them no problem with the following command...

```
set PGPASSWORD=password
psql -U USERNAME Database_Name
\copy (SELECT * FROM table1) TO C:\xyz\exportfile.csv CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;
```

The problem I am running into is the .csv is meant to be used with Tableau, however, when importing to excel I run into the same issue. It turns text fields into integers in both Tableau and Excel. This causes issues specifically on joining serial numbers on the Tableau side.

I know I can change these fields in Tableau/Excel manually but I am trying to find a way to make sure the end-user wouldn't need to do this. I'd like for them to just drag and drop the updated .csv postgresql data extracts and be able to start Tableau no problem. They don't seem real tech-savvy. I know you can connect Tableau directly to Postgres but in this particular case, I am not allowed to due to limitations beyond my control.

I'm using PostgreSQL 12 and Tableau v2019.4.0

EDIT: As request providing example data! Both of the fields are TEXT inside of PostgreSQL but the export doesn't specify.

```
Excel Formatting
ASSETNUM,ITEMNUM
1834,8.11234E+12
1835,8.11234E+12

Notepad Formatting
ASSETNUM,ITEMNUM
1834,8112345673294
1835,8112345673295
```

Note: If you select the specific cell in Excel it shows the full number.

Comment: Can you show a sample line of your CSV, no need for it to have actual real data, just make sure the data TYPES are accurate. You may need to make your query to output varchar fields that contains only numbers to be exported as text

Comment: Side note: maybe the title isn't so gud.

Comment: Yeah should only take a few minutes.

Comment: Check here https://superuser.com/q/318420 this thread may share some light into your problem.

Comment: @JorgeCampos that does clear things up. But, my understanding is I'd have to change the record values to ="number" for it to export correctly?

Comment: @JorgeCampos also is there a way to specify data type on export, both of those are just TEXT fields in PostgreSQL but the export doesn't specify.

Comment: What I've done in the past when I was with such a problem was concatenating a blank space at the end of varchar fields that has only numbers, so something like `select varcharFieldThatHasOnlyNumbers || ' ' as columnName .....` isn't pretty but it works

Comment: Another more elegant solution would be to use the `FORCE_QUOTE` option of the copy command as stated in the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html however I never tried it myself... my previous comment solution was good enough ;)

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate it @Jorge Campos. I did try the FORCE_QUOTE but (I think the other thread mentioned this as well) it only add "" around the fields. I think to get Tableau/Excel to recognize it correctly I need ="recordvalue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV files don't have any type information, so programs like Excel/Tableau are free to interpret the data how they like.

However, @JorgeCampos's link provides useful information. For example

```
"=""123""","=""123"""
```

gets interpreted differently than

```
123,123
```

when you load it into Excel.

If you want to add quotes to your data, the easiest way is to use PostgreSQL's [string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html), e.g.

```
SELECT '"=""' || my_column || '"""' FROM my_database
```

Comment: I believe I am going to use this method. I think you have to add the = as well to make it work properly. I did also try @Jorge Campos second suggestion FORCE_QUOTE however, it does not add the = to the beginning just "" which, can cause issues.